# jquery filter based on substr range

Tags: jquery

how can we modify this code to filter out dates(as substr in yyyymmdd format) other than in the range provided.

```
<select id="all">
    <option value="abc_20010315_Volvo_A">Volvo_A</option>
    <option value="defg_20020408_saab_B">saab_B</option>
    <option value="xz_20100120_Volvo_C">Volvo_C</option>
</select>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
<button type="button" id="filter">Filter</button>
```

dates are received in yyyymmdd format from the range selector.

```
function Filter(val){
var from = $("#from").val();
var to = $("#to").val();
  $("#all > option").each(function() {
    $(this).show();
    if(?){
      $(this).hide();
    }
  }); 
}
```

What function can i use to compare date in a string as substring?
Thanks.

I have done this but it still has some problem.

```
$( "#Filter" ).click(function( event ) {
    var from = $("#from").val();
    var match = from.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/);
    from = parseInt(match[1] + match[2] + match[3]);

    var to = $("#to").val();
    var match = to.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/);
    to = parseInt(match[1] + match[2] + match[3]);

    var regex = /\d{8}/i;
    $("#all> option").each(function(){
        $(this).show();
        var opt = this.value;
        var dateValue = parseInt(opt.match(regex));
        if(dateValue < from && dateValue > to){
          $(this).hide();
        }
    }); 
    $("#all")[0].selectedIndex = 0;

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You cannot hide an option of the select tag.

Comment: ofcourse we can.
I am trying to filter options out based on date range selected.

Comment: Ok. But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: for example if from variable had received value 20100101 and to variable had value 20101230 than i want to hide the first two options. Because the time stamp on it is out of the range provided.

Comment: Thats fine but the from and to fields are text fields which return strings. Do you expect string on the first part? Having said that, I would like you to use a calendar component.

Comment: You can convert the date to `timestamp` and do normal comparision.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. For anyone who might run in similar problem.
Here is my solution.

```
// implementation code for filter by date range
$( "#Filter" ).click(function( event ) {
    var from = $("#from").val();
    var match = from.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/);
    from = parseInt(match[1] + match[2] + match[3]);

    var to = $("#to").val();
    var match = to.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/);
    to = parseInt(match[1] + match[2] + match[3]);

    var regex = /\d{8}/i;
    $("#all > option").each(function(){
        $(this).show();
        var opt = this.value;
        var dateValue = parseInt(opt.match(regex));
        var test = dateValue < from || dateValue > to ;
        //alert("dateValue:"+dateValue+" test:"+test);
        if(test){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }); 
    $("#all")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```